# How to start in VR with google cardboard?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

what material or documentation do I need to read to start developing in VR for Cardboard and Unity. Remembering that I've read the introduction offered by Google, but that doesn't seem enough.

Comment: You need to import the Google VR for Unity package: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/releases

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The official Quickstart for Google Cardboard for Unity is pretty much all you need for the VR part. The rest is pure game dev on Unity.

https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart